# What is the difference between a dictionary and a hashtable in Swift?

Tags: swift, data-structures

I want to understand how dictionary implemented. If hashtable is a list of a key value pairs, what is the dictionary? Does it use hash function to calculate an index to store the element?

Comment: There is no hashtable type in swift but Dictionary is a hash table

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, i didn't find an inner implementation of a dictionary in swift. But there is no stored keys in a hashtable, but the dictionary stores (key, value) pairs together...